# mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow start twice

Tags: android

For buy i have code

```
 public void onClick(View v) 
 {              
       // FIRST CHECK IF THE USER IS ALREADY A SUBSCRIBER.
       mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(SubscribeIntroActivity.this, SUBSCRIBE_SKU, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener);    
 }


 public void onClick(View v) 
 {              
       // FIRST CHECK IF THE USER IS ALREADY A SUBSCRIBER.
       mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(SubscribeIntroActivity.this, SUBSCRIBE_SKU, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener);    
 }

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Error purchasing: " + result);

            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");

            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
            // bought the premium upgrade!
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
            Log.d(TAG,"Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
            mIsPremium = true;
            isShortVersion=false;
            DrawIsShortVersion();
        }

        }
    };
```

Error in LOG IS

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress.
```

when i click button its open buyer dialog and i can buy without any problem, but if i click button dialog is opened, **Push BACK hardware button on device** (didnt buy) i see first activity with **button BUY**, push it for buy again and raise error. May be somebody know about this error? what i do wrong?

... added  if (mHelper != null) mHelper.flagEndAsync(); before call launchPurchaseFlow, now no errors, but mHelper.flagEndAsync(); kill previos task ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Logs?
In most cases an error occours when an Async PurcaseFlow is running and yout try to run an other Purcase.
what are you doing in your Purcase Listener?

Edit: you have multiple Coices to make that:

First: create a global boolean -> mTaskIsRunning;

```
private void doBuyProduct(int id){
  if(!mTaskIsRunning){
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(SubscribeIntroActivity.this, SUBSCRIBE_SKU, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener);  
   mTaskIsRunning=true;
}
}
```

Then in your Listener:
....

```
mTaskIsRunning=false;
```

Or you can disable the Buttons while a Task is Running 
Same Procedure :

```
private void doBuyProduct(int id){
      disableBuyButtons();
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(SubscribeIntroActivity.this, SUBSCRIBE_SKU, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener);  


    }
```

and in the FinishListener:

```
enableButtons();
```